# How to concatenate and pass parameters values in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to get values from ajax rest call, I'm trying to concatenate these values into an 'a' tag in order to create a pagination section for my results (picture attached).

I'm sending the HTML (divHTMLPages) but the result is not well-formed and not working, I've tried with double quotes and single but still not well-formed. So, I wonder if this is a good approach to accomplish what I need to create the pagination. The 'a' tag is going to trigger the onclick event with four parameters (query for rest call, department, row limit and the start row for display)

```
  if (_startRow == 0) {
    console.log("First page");
    var currentPage = 1;
    // Set Next Page
    var nextPage = 2;
    var startRowNextPage = _startRow + _rowLimit + 1;
    var query = $('#queryU').val();     
    // page Link
    divHTMLPages = "<strong>1</strong>&nbsp;";
    divHTMLPages += "<a href='#' onclick='getRESTResults(" + query + "', '" + _reg + "', " + _rowLimit + ", " + _startRow + ")>" + nextPage + "</a> ";
    console.log("Next page: " + nextPage);
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

[Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYKku.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to type out how the function should be called in an HTML string, it would be much more elegant to attach an event listener to the element in question. For example, assuming the parent element you're inserting elements into is called `parent`, you could do something like this:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '#';
a.textContent = nextPage;
a.onclick = () => getRESTResults(query, _reg, _rowLimit, _startRow);
parent.appendChild(a);
```

Once an event listener is attached, like with the `onclick` above, make sure not to change the `innerHTML` of the container (like with `innerHTML += <something>`), because that will corrupt any existing listeners inside the container - instead, append elements explicitly with methods like `createElement` and `appendChild`, as shown above, or use `insertAdjacentHTML` (which does not re-parse the whole container's contents).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach but I had to use append instead of appendChild because I had an exception that appendChild is not a function. I see the href, textContent and others elements but the onclick is not filling up in the tag, am I missing something else?

Comment: `appendChild` *should* work, if you selected (or created) the parent element normally. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/djbqhuwo/ The listener works too. You don't want an `onclick` *attribute* - rather, you want a listener attached via Javascript, which you won't see in the HTML text.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function()
{
var query=10;
var _reg="12";
var _rowLimit="test";
var _startRow="aa";
var nextPage="testhref";
//before divHTMLPages+=,must be define divHTMLPages value
var divHTMLPages = "<a href='#' onclick=getRESTResults('"+query + "','" + _reg + "','" + _rowLimit + "','" + _startRow + "')>" + nextPage + "</a>";
///or use es6 `` Template literals
var divHTMLPages1 = `<a href="#" onclick="getRESTResults('`+query + `','` + _reg + `','` + _rowLimit + `','` + _startRow +`')">` + nextPage + `</a>`;
$("#test").append("<div>"+divHTMLPages+"</div>");
$("#test").append("<div>"+divHTMLPages1+"</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```